# I am unable to input download link in html

Tags: html, css, pdf, download, href

I am receiving the error "Failed- No file" whenever I tried to click the download button. Here is the code below:

```
<a class="btn-ghost" href="Resume/cover letter.pdf" download>Download resume</a>
```

is there anything I can do to rectify the error?

Comment: you have an whitespace in the URL thats why it does not work

Comment: I removed the whitespace. Still the same thing

Comment: Do not remove the space from link encode your URL; <a class="btn-ghost" href="Resume/cover%20letter.pdf" download>Download resume</a>

Comment: umm thats what i thought i tried it

Comment: You tried to open `Resume/cover%20letter.pdf` in saperate tab to check if it is working

Answer (score -1):

```html
<a class="btn-ghost" download href="Resume/cover letter.pdf" download>Download resume</a>
```

You can try this one also and again check the path you have given to the href, if the path is correct then this will gonna run, i have tried it.